# Accessing Pervasive Database via Node.js on a Linux Server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-server, pervasive

Our business system uses a [Pervasive 13](https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/#page/getstart%2F04nstunx.htm%23ww78332) database. I want to query this database from [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) on an [Ubuntu Linux 18.01 server](https://www.ubuntu.com/server), but I can't seem to find any tutorials that show how to do this.

With other databases, I've been able to find npm packages that simplify database communication, but I've yet to locate one for Pervasive.

Linux drivers are offered, but I'm not sure how to ultimately query the database from node.js. Any general advise or resources pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: That article describes implementing a .NET WCF service to access the db on the server side, to produce the data for a javascript client. A step in the right direction but not quite right.

Comment: Take a look at the odbc npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc).  It should let you connect to the Pervasive ODBC driver on Linux.   I haven't tried it but if it implements the ODBC standard, you should be able to connect to you Pervasive database.

Comment: @mirtheil : One of the requirements of that package is to have ODBC drivers for the target database. On our windows clients, there are ODBC drivers that are allowing us to connect to pervasive, but I'm not sure how to implement the odbc drivers on the Linux server.

Comment: You don't need to implement them, with PSQL v11, Linux ODBC drivers are included with the Linux client (at http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv11.aspx).  If you install the PSQL client, you'll get the ODBC drivers.

Comment: I'm just curious about if you found a solution to this problem? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @robbannn - I haven't had time yet. If you get this going, please report back. I'll do the same if I beat your to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help, it's an NPM package for accessing OData data sources in node.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-odata

Comment: Ultimately, I just trying to send a sql query to pervasive and get something back I can at least convert to json.