# How to connect to PervasiveSQL via PHP+Ubuntu14

Tags: php, ubuntu, pervasive-sql

I'm trying to connect to a PervasiveSQL database (on a remote machine) via PHP 7 running on Ubuntu 14.

I have a line like the following, which gives me `Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect` error.

```
$connect = odbc_connect("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface};ServerName=SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;ServerDSN=DATABASE_NAME;", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

I tried following [this](https://communities.actian.com/s/question/0D53300003y5u4ACAQ/ubuntu-32bit-pervasive-odbc) tutorial (the latest response from Jari Kallonen). However, it doesn't work for me. I'm not sure if I understand the concept of DSN - is it supposed to be the database name that I'm trying to query against?

Comment: A DSN is a 'name' for the datasouce so that applications can connect to them instead of having to remember all of the connection details.  The DSN points to the engine where the database resides.   Is your PHP 32 or 64 bit?  What version of PervasiveSQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP 64 bit, and PSQL 13. So, is it okay to simply not provide ServerDSN to odbc_connect string? I did try it, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Try using the "Pervasive ODBC Interface" instead of the "Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface".  Does change the error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. I also tried with "Pervasive ODBC Client Interface".

Comment: Okay, let's step back.  You're using PSQL v13, Ubuntu 14, and PHP 7.  What exact version / product do you have installed on the Ubuntu machine?  What does 'php -v' show from the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: `php -v` returns `PHP 5.6.30 (cli)`. But, I'm testing via Apache Web Server, which is running `PHP Version 7.1.8-2+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+4`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179340/discussion-between-mirtheil-and-cheeku-jee).

Comment: I really wish I could find a tutorial (video or article) where someone successfully sets up the client on Linux. This is very important to me, but [I can't figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476064/) and there's no help.